# Symfony not matching /finding any routes

Tags: symfony1, routes, symfony-1.4

After updating the application including some new routes, symfony can't match any of the routes:

```
symfony [err] {sfConfigurationException} Unable to find a matching route to generate url for params "array (  'action' => 'changeLanguage',  'module' => 'language',  'culture' => 'en_US',)"
```

What do I need to to do to make symfony find/match the routes again?

So here is my routing 
Routing.yml

```
<?php $cultures = implode(I18NUtils::availableCultures(), '|') ?>

locality_list:
  url:  /:sf_culture/orte/:slug.:season.:id.:sf_format
  class: sfPropelRoute
  options: { model: Locality, type: object }
  param: { module: locality, action: list, sf_format: html }
  requirements:
    id: \d+
    sf_method: [get]

locality_info:
  url:  /:sf_culture/orte/:slug.:season.:id.details.:sf_format
  class: sfPropelRoute
  options: { model: Locality, type: object }
  param: { module: locality, action: show, sf_format: html }
  requirements:
    id: \d+
    sf_method: [get]

housings_by_category:
  url:  /:sf_culture/category/:slugs
  param: { module: housing, action: listByCategory, sf_format: html }
  requirements:
    sf_culture: (?:<?php echo $cultures ?>)

housings_by_tag_locality:
  url:  /:sf_culture/tag/:tags/:locality_id
  param: { module: housing, action: listByTag, sf_format: html }
  requirements:
    sf_culture: (?:<?php echo $cultures ?>)

housings_by_tag:
  url:  /:sf_culture/tag/:tags
  param: { module: housing, action: listByTag, sf_format: html }
  requirements:
    sf_culture: (?:<?php echo $cultures ?>)

housings_by_locality:
  url:  /:sf_culture/:slug.:season.:id.list.:sf_format
  class: sfPropelRoute
  options: { model: Locality, type: object }
  param: { module: housing, action: list, sf_format: html }
  requirements:
    id: \d+
    sf_method: [get]

housing_info:
  url:  /:sf_culture/:slug.:season.:id.:sf_format
  class: sfPropelRoute
  options: { model: Housing, type: object }
  param: { module: housing, action: show, sf_format: html }
  requirements:
    id: \d+
    sf_method: [get]

housings:
  url: /:sf_culture/
  param: { module: housing, action: index }
  requirements:
    sf_culture: (?:<?php echo $cultures ?>)

hut_details:
  url:  /:sf_culture/huetten/:slug.:season.:id.:sf_format
  class: sfPropelRoute
  options: { model: Housing, type: object }
  param: { module: housing, action: show, sf_format: html }
  requirements:
    id: \d+
    sf_method: [get]

huts:
  url: /:sf_culture/huetten
  param: { module: hut, action: index }
  requirements:
    sf_culture: (?:<?php echo $cultures ?>)

legacy_redirect:
  url: /incoming/:action/*
  param: { module: legacysite, sf_format: html }

home:
  url:  /
  param: { module: home, action: index }

localized_home:
    url:    /:sf_culture/
    param:  { module: home, action: index  }
    requirements:
        sf_culture: (?:<?php echo $cultures ?>)

change_language:
    url:    /language
    param:  { module: language, action: changeLanguage }

# default rules
default_index:
  url:   /:sf_culture/:module
  param: { action: index }
  requirements:
    sf_culture: (?:<?php echo $cultures ?>)

default:
  url:   /:sf_culture/:module/:action/*
  param: { sf_format: html }
  requirements:
    sf_culture: (?:<?php echo $cultures ?>)
```

Comment: could you add your `routing.yml` in the question?

Comment: What version of symfony is this?

Answer (score 0):

You need the `culture` param to your `change_language` route:

```
change_language:
    url:    /language/:culture
    param:  { module: language, action: changeLanguage }
```

Maybe with your requirements too.